# Is it possible to use results of loops in openscads quicksort()

Tags: loops, quicksort, using, openscad

Arrays openScad : I need to use the results of nested loops in quicksort() function but it seems impossible.

'arr' in second last line (in code below) will not contain more than one value at a time. In the first run of the loop arr gets the value 2.01, in second run the value is 1.6125, and so on.
 What I need is an array containing all four values in this way: arr=[[2.01],[1.6125],[3.775],[4.8]], 
 because quicksort above needs such an input.
 If is it possible to achieve that in openScad, how do I do it?

```
function quicksort(arr) = !(len(arr)>0) ? [] : let(
pivot   = arr[floor(len(arr)/2)],
lesser  = [ for (y = arr) if (y  < pivot) y ],
equal   = [ for (y = arr) if (y == pivot) y ],
greater = [ for (y = arr) if (y  > pivot) y ]
) concat(quicksort(lesser), equal, quicksort(greater));

x_0=262; y_0=140; x_1=17.5;y_1=305;x_2=500;y_2=255; x_3=575;y_3=385;

ads=[[x_0,y_0],[x_1,y_1],[x_2,y_2],[x_3,y_3]];
for(b=[0 : 3])
{
 for(c=[0:0])
    if(ads[b][0]>=0 && ads[b][1]>=0)
    {         
            asc_diff=((ads[b][0])+ads[b][1])/2*0.01;                    
            arr=asc_diff; 
            //quicksort(arr) ;          
            echo("27: arr", arr); 
      }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set all values of the array at initialization using either hardcoded values or functions that rely on hardcoded values. So yes, you can create an array whose values are calculated but you have to do all calculations in place at initialization. This could look like this:

```
arr = [asc_diff(element_1), asc_diff(element_2), ... , asc_diff(element_n)];
```

For nested loops this would become rather difficult and cumbersome. You could write a C program that generates the OpenSCAD code for you. Or you might wanna check out OpenJSCAD. OpenJSCAD is object-oriented and has some more coding functionality than OpenSCAD.